# Package `sentimentr`: how remove emoticons and stopwords before `sentiment_by`

Tags: r, text-mining, sentiment-analysis, sentimentr

Here is a basic sentiment example. The text data is splitted into sentences via the `get_sentences` function. With `sentiment_by` we approximate the sentiment (polarity) of text for an entire element of a list (`mytext` in this example).

E.g. for the example:

```
library(sentimentr)

mytext <- c(
  'do you like it?  But I hate really bad dogs',
  'I am the best friend.',
  'Do you really like it?  I\'m not a fan'
)

mytext <- get_sentences(mytext)
sentiment_by(mytext)
```

I obtained the following result:

```
   element_id word_count       sd ave_sentiment
1:          1         10 1.497465    -0.8088680
2:          2          5       NA     0.5813777
3:          3          9 0.284605     0.2196345
```

Before applying sentiment function, I would like to remove stop words, number, emoticons from `mytext`. I figured I could use, e.g:

```
library("tm")
tm_map(mytext, removeNumbers)
tm_map(mytext, removeWords, stopwords())
```

but I obtained:

```
Error in UseMethod("tm_map", x) : 
 no applicable method for 'tm_map' applied to an object of class "c('get_sentences', 
'get_sentences_character', 'list')"
```

Comment: `tm_map` accepts a corpus according to their documentation and here `mytext` is of class `"get_sentences"           "get_sentences_character" "list" `

Comment: When using sentimentr, you do not need to remove the stopwords. It doesn't change the sentiment calculation. Same goes for the numbers. When using sentimentr, you can use `replace_emoticon` to change the emoticons into word equivalents. Check all the documentation that is available in the textclean package. This is installed when you installed sentimentr.

Comment: Thank you! @phiver, why I do not need to remove the stopwords? Pakcage manual doesn't explain it.

Comment: The [sentimentr github page](https://github.com/trinker/sentimentr) explains it a bit better, but the sentiment is scored against a dictionary. Stopwords are not a part of this dictionary and even if they are, they would have a score of 0.